# TypeError: Discord.MessageAttachment is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, discord.js, interaction

I want to output the json file you pulled from mysql with a txt file because it is long, but it gives an error

I want to send it as txt because the file is too long

```
const interactionCreate = require("../events/interactionCreate");
const Parser = require('rss-parser');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const parser = new Parser()
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9')
const { request } = require('undici')
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs")
const jsonToTxt = require("json-to-txt");
const Discord = require("discord.js")
module.exports = {
    
    name: "adsoyad",
    description: "ad soyad bilgi ",
    options:[
        {
            name: "adı",
            description: "sorgulanacak kişi ismi",
            type: 3,
            required: true,     
                    
        },
        {
            name: "soyadı",
            description : "sorgulanacak kişi soyadı",
            type: 3,
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: "il",
            description: "sorgulanacak kişinin oturduğu il / listelemeyi azaltır",
            type: 3,
            required: false
        }
       
    ],
    run: async (client, interaction, str) =>{
        const { member, channelId, guildId, applicationId,
            commandName, deferred, replied, ephemeral,
            options, id, createdTimestamp, MessageAttachment
        } = interaction;
        const { guild } = member;
        try {
            var mysql = require('mysql');
            var con = mysql.createConnection({
              host     : 'localhost',
              user     : 'root',
              password : '',
              database : '101m'
            });
        
            var isim = interaction.options.getString("isim")
            var soyisim = interaction.options.getString("soyisim")
            var il = interaction.options.getString("il")



            if (il) {
                con.query(`SELECT * FROM 101m WHERE ADI="${isim}" AND SOYADI="${soyisim}" AND NUFUSIL="${il}"`, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))
      

                    let as31 = data.map((o) => `${o.TC} ${o.ADI} ${o.SOYADI} ${o.DOGUMTARIHI} ${o.NUFUSIL} ${o.NUFUSILCE} ${o.ANNEADI} ${o.ANNETC} ${o.BABAADI} ${o.BABATC} ${o.UYRUK}`).join('\n')
                    const Discord = require('discord.js')
                  // let dosyahazırla = new Discord.MessageAttachment (
                    const embedmesaj = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setColor("DarkGrey")
                    .setTitle(`:tada: ${isim} ${soyisim} isminde  **${data.length}** kişi bulundu`)
                    .setDescription(`${as31}`)
                    .setFooter({text:`%64 Bot Developed By Mars`})
                   interaction.reply({  embeds: [embedmesaj] , ephemeral: true })
                   

                })  
            } else { 
                  con.query(`SELECT * FROM 101m WHERE ADI="${isim}" AND SOYADI="${soyisim}"`, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))
                

                let as31 = data.map((o) => `${o.TC} ${o.ADI} ${o.SOYADI} ${o.DOGUMTARIHI} ${o.NUFUSIL} ${o.NUFUSILCE} ${o.ANNEADI} ${o.ANNETC} ${o.BABAADI} ${o.BABATC} ${o.UYRUK}`).join('\n')
                const Discord = require("discord.js")
                let dosyahazırla = new Discord.MessageAttachment(Buffer.from(as31), 'slm.txt')
                const embedmesaj = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("DarkGrey")
                .setTitle(`:tada: ${isim} ${soyisim} isminde  **${data.length}** kişi bulundu`)
            
                .setFooter({text:`%64 Bot Developed By Mars`})
               interaction.reply({embeds: [embedmesaj], ephemeral: true})
               interaction.channel.send({ files: [ dosyahazırla ] })
               
           
            }); 
      }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(String(e.stack).bgRed)
  }


 }        
}
```

i run it but this is the error i get

```
  throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: Discord.MessageAttachment is not a constructor
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\commands\adsoyad.js:84:36)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Sequence.end (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:133:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\trwor\OneDrive\Masaüstü\%64 bot Project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)

Node.js v18.14.0
```

Thank you from now

Isn't there a way to solve this error? A quick solution would be great both for me and for you :)

Comment: Are you using discord.js v14? `MessageAttachment` has been renamed to `AttachmentBuilder`

Comment: yes discord.js v14 bro

Comment: You'll need to use `new Discord.AttachmentBuilder(Buffer.from(as31), { name: 'slm.txt' })` then.

Comment: dude converts it to jpg file but

Comment: bro error it's still problematic, this time it resets the data without throwing anything away

Comment: It sounds like a different question. You can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the details so we can help you

Comment: I asked bro can you help me please